# NSDateFormatter gives same date, wont update in loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Why isn't the last date updating, input is correct, see trace...

Code

```
// Date
self.dateLabel.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:item.pubDate dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[self.dateLabel sizeToFit];
NSLog(@"pubDate is %@ formated date is %@", item.pubDate,[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:item.pubDate dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]);
```

Output

```
pubDate is 2015-03-30 01:00:00 +0000 formated date is 30/03/2015
pubDate is 2015-03-30 01:00:00 +0000 formated date is 30/03/2015
pubDate is 2015-03-29 23:00:00 +0000 formated date is 30/03/2015
```

Comment: It may depend on the device timezone setting. E.g. 11pm in one timezone is the next day in another timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mats yes - even though the input string contained timezome offset and the device is set to UK format

Input has timezone specified:

stringDate is March 30, 2015 from 2015-03-30 01:00:00 +0000.

pubDate is 2015-03-30 01:00:00 +0000 formated date is 30/03/2015.

stringDate is March 30, 2015 from 2015-03-29 23:00:00 +0000.

pubDate is 2015-03-29 23:00:00 +0000 formated date is 30/03/2015.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
self.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:item.pubDate];
```

not

```
self.dateLabel.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:item.pubDate dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

Seems overkill but it works